# Django 1.6: Save form data temporarily between pages

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm creating a user review form where patients can leave a review on their doctors. I only want logged in users to write a review and only 1 review per user per doctor. The user is shown a review form regardless if she's signed in. If not logged in, upon clicking submit button the page is redirected to login form and after successful authentication it's redirected back to the doctor profile. But the form data is lost when the user is redirected.

How do i save the form data temporarily so that it stays there when the user comesback after successful authentication and can submit the form? I've read it somewhere you can use sessions but everything is so overwhelming and too confusing for me to understand.

**docprofile.html**

```
{% if reviewed == False %}
<form action="" method="post" id="user_uploader" > {% csrf_token %}
<div class="revbox">
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="comment" placeholder="How was your experience?" name="comment" rows="6"></textarea>

<div class="subbox">
<div class="like-dis-check">
<p id="wouldrec"> Would you recommmend this doctor to someone else?</p>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="Like" value="Like">
<label id="r1" for="radio1">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="Like" value="Dislike">
<label id="r2" for="radio2">No</label>
</div>

<div class="drop1">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.id }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="doctor" value="{{ doctor.id }}" />
</div>

{% if not user.is_authenticated %}

<div class="subbutton">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}" type="" name="submit" id="ss-submit">Submit</a>
</div>

{% else %}

<div class="subbutton">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit"id="ss-submit">Submit</button>
</div>

{% endif %} 


<div class="errorbox">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
{{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
{% elif user.is_authenticated and reviewed == True  %}
<h4><a class="writebtn">Already Reviewed!</a></h4>
{% else %}
<a class="btn btn-primary writebtn" onclick = " ga('send','event', 'button' , 'Write a Review', 'Dr. {{doctor.name}}', 7);" href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Write a Review</a>  
{% endif %}
```

**view.py**

```
def showDocProfile(request, slug):

    doctor = get_object_or_404(Doctor, slug=slug)

    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Dr. " + doctor.name +"  "+ doctor.specialization.name +"})

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserContentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']


            if request.POST.get('Like') == 'Like':
                con = UserContent(comment = comment, liked = True, disliked = False, doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.likes += 1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                doctor.save()
                con.save()

            elif request.POST.get('Like') == 'Dislike':
                con = UserContent(comment = comment, liked = False, disliked = True,  doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.dislikes +=1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                doctor.save()
                con.save()

            url = '/docprofile/%s' % str(doctor.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = UserContentForm()

    UGC = UserContent.objects.filter(doctor_id=doctor.id).order_by('-submitted_on') # Reviews on Meddy


    d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'UGC': UGC,'form': form,  'doctors': Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-rating')})
    return render(request, 'm1/docprofile.html', d)
```

Comment: The session is indeed how you would do it. But I don't see anything in that code that redirects if the user isn't logged in; where is that happening?

Comment: in docprofile. {% if not user.is_authenticated %}. When the user clicks the submit button it's redirected to a login page.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the redirect in the template is the wrong place. There's no opportunity to save it in the session if you do that. Instead, you should always submit to your `showDocProfile` view, and do the redirect there if necessary:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    user = request.user
else:
    request.session['doctor_data'] = request.POST
    return redirect("{}?{}".format(reverse('login'), request.path))
if request.method == "POST":
...
else:
    data = request.session.pop('doctor_data', None)
    form = UserContentForm(data)
...
```

Comment: but this way users can't even see the doctor profile without being logged in, let alone try to write a review. I want to prompt the login upon form submission.

Comment: OK, so move that logic inside the `request.method==POST` check.